# Working of perl sockets

Tags: perl, sockets

I am a beginner to Perl socket programming. As of now, the server sends a string and the client responds with another string in my program. Later, if the server sends another string, the client is not able to receive it. To transfer data between the server and client for multiple times, should I include any functions?

SERVER:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket;
my $clientsocket;
my $serverdata;
my $clientdata;

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => 2500,
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    Listen    => 1,
    Reuse     => 1
) or die "Oops: $! \n";

print "Waiting for the Client.\n";
$clientsocket = $socket->accept();
print   "Connected from : ", $clientsocket->peerhost();
print   ", Port : ", $clientsocket->peerport(), "\n";

# Write some data to the client  
$serverdata = "This is the Server speaking \n";
print $clientsocket "$serverdata \n";

# read the data from the client
$clientdata = <$clientsocket>;
print "$clientdata";
$serverdata = "Server Again writing \n";
print $clientsocket "$serverdata";

$socket->close();
```

CLIENT:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Tk;

my $socket;
my $serverdata;
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
    PeerPort => '2500',
    Proto    => 'tcp',
) or die "$!\n";

print "Connected to the Server.\n";

# read the message sent by server.
$serverdata = <$socket>;
print "Message from Server : $serverdata \n";

# Send some message to server.
my $name = "Client here!";
print $socket "$name";

# Read message sent by server.
$serverdata = <$socket>;
print "$serverdata";

$socket->close();
```

Printing of $serverdata second time in the Client side is not happening.

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to give any kind of sensible answer

Comment: Please show us your Server and Client you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server starts listening on some port. It waits until a client connects, the `accept`s that connection. It reads and writes a bit of data over the client connection. And then? Then it just closes the socket and exits the program.

That is not what you intended: You want the server to start waiting for the next connection. That means some kind of loop: Each time a client connects, we'll do our communication:

```
while (my $client = $socket->accept) {
    # do something with the $client
}
```

I recommend you read through the relevant sections of [`perldoc perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#TCP-Servers-with-IO%3a%3aSocket), but keep in mind it uses outdated best practices, so don't directly copy anything.

Comment: If the server is going to just close the socket and exit, how is it possible that a second message from client to server could be read by the server? I modified the above code such that the client sends a 2nd message before it just closes. And, the server seems to receive it without any trouble. I have not used the while loop yet!

Comment: @user2691811 Quite simple: don't close the socket before the next client arrives. The central point is that the `accept` should happen in a *loop*, not only *once*.

Comment: I guess, my problem is with the server sending multiple messages. The client is very well able to send multiple messages. I don't get the idea of server closing its socket. If that is the case, how is it able to receive data from client?

Comment: Yes, the problem is *purely* server side. If you look into your code, you will see that the server `accept`s a client, communicates a bit, and then does `$socket->close()` – of the listening socket, not of `$clientsocket`. After that, another client is trying to connect, but the server isn't listening! (I'd expect the client to time out). The server *needs* a loop so that it can handle one client after each other.

Comment: @user2691811 I think my answer describes a problem, but not the problem you are asking about – Ingo's answer points out a more immediate problem: The client should `print $socket "$stuff\n"` ← notice the newline at the end. The `<$clientsocket>` wants to read a whole line until the end of the file or the end of the line – but the socket stays open and no newline is ever sent. Also, the client should do `$socket->autoflush(1)`

Comment: @amon : Could you provide some information on where to get more up-to-date IPC best practices?

Comment: @Zaid Sorry, I don't know a good source. `perlipc` isn't wrong, it just uses outdated style (bareword filehandles everywhere), and doesn't know about [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run). It's as if that page had never been touched after Modern Perl became a thing. Would you like to volunteer to rewrite it? ;-)

Comment: @amon : I'm hardly an expert (you've seen my profile, right? ;) )

Answer (score 2):

If you use  to read message from another end, the sender must end the message with "\n".
Alternatively, you can use recv(...) so the message won't be buffered till newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your client sends a whole line. SInce you are reading with

```
<$clientsocket>
```

your server waits for a "\n" from the client.